# Como organizar no projeto as viewmodels e mapeamentos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia pessoal !
Estou estudando sobre mapeamento (model e viewmodel), utilizando implicit operators. 
Mas me surgiu uma dúvida: Como organizar as viewmodels e mapeamentos dentro do projeto ? 
Onde devo salvar as classes ? Dentro do arquivo da classe do model ou criar uma própria ou até, uma pasta somente para viewmodels ?
E sobre o mapeamento, qual "local" devo escrever o código ?

Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda !

Comment: Olá @Renato, essa pergunta está um pouco ampla. Seria melhor se separar em perguntas menores e exemplificar o que deseja, assim será mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: Exemplo: Tenho o model Usuario e a viewmodel Login. Como vou mapear "na mão" (implicit operators), a dúvida é organizacional.  Primeira dúvida:  crio a classe viewmodel Login no arquivo model Usuario ? Segunda dúvida: O mapeamento, aonde devo criá-la ? No arquivo model Usuario ? Perdoe-me não ser mais explicito.

Comment: Então Renato, essa dúvida está ampla. Você quer saber como fazer? Onde fazer? Nome dos diretórios onde colocar as classes? Todas essas são perguntas diferentes, o que deixa a sua pergunta ampla

Comment: Como disse, é uma dúvida organizacional, de como deve ficar a estrutura do projeto. Crio um pasta somente para viewmodels ?

Comment: Geralmente é criado uma pasta para `ViewModels`, deixando assim uma organização melhor. Isto é, se tiver utilizando uma estrutura padrão MVC.

Comment: Sim, é MVC. Agradeço a orientação !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que ViewModels servem apenas para servir às modelagens/tipagens das Views, ela deve ficar no projeto de apresentação - se for MVC, no projeto Web, se for WebAPI, no projeto de API. Não devem ficar no mesmo projeto das models, pois pertencem à outro contexto.

Para ajudar no mapeamento de `Models <-> ViewModels`, eu utilizo o [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). Muito fácil de implementar e bem rápido. Segue um arquivo do [Eduardo Pires](http://eduardopires.net.br)  sobre [AutoMapper e ViewModels](http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-utilizando-automapper-com-view-model-pattern/). Irá te ajudar a implementar esse pattern.

Comment: Agradeço pela indicação ! vou estudar o AutoMapper

Comment: Ok, fiquei curioso. Pq da negativada?

Comment: Amigão, devo ter me enganado ao "tickar". Corrigido. Mas, negativou o meu pq ? rs